# What is the origin of the phrase "when push comes to shove"?

Tags: etymology, expressions

"When push comes to shove" means "as a last resort" or "if absolutely necessary". Does anyone know why the phrase came to be used in this way?

Comment: I always just assumed it meant, "when the going gets rough". As in, "when a polite push is changes to a forceful shove".

Comment: This is really old, but I've just looked it up. [According to Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/when_push_comes_to_shove), it means, "When one must commit oneself to an action or decision." [The OED says](https://oed.com/view/Entry/155116?redirectedFrom=when+push+comes+to+shove#eid27599880), "when action must back up words; if or when one must commit oneself to an action or decision." That is how I always understood it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [site](http://www.chacha.com/question/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-%27when-push-comes-to-shove%27), this term comes from rugby, where, after an infraction of rules, forwards from each team face off and push against one another.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure about this rugby scrum origin theory. I found a [snippet](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&noj=1&biw=1280&bih=705&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&q=%22AJ%20Gracia%20of%20Southbury%22&aq=f&aqi=m1&aql=&oq=) of a 1981 William Safire column in *New York Times Magazine* article that indicates this guess was put forth by an AJ Gracia of Southbury, Connecticut. It goes on to call it an "offbeat etymology."

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=push) has the phrase dated from 1958, but with no mention of rugby. I found the phrase used over a decade earlier ([1947](http://books.google.com/books?id=jRFDEQGhMLEC&printsec=frontcover#v=snippet&q=%22english%20translation,%20the%20estate%22&f=false)) in the English translation of Haitian Jacques Romain's *[Masters of the Dew](http://books.google.com/books?id=jRFDEQGhMLEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=editions:jRFDEQGhMLEC#v=snippet&q=%22when%20push%20comes%20to%20shove%22&f=false)* done by Langston Hughes and Mercer Cook. Again, no rugby context:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=jRFDEQGhMLEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=editions:jRFDEQGhMLEC#v=snippet&q=%22when%20push%20comes%20to%20shove%22&f=false]

It would be interesting to know what original French phrase was translated as such. Hughes went on to use the phrase again in *Simple Takes a Wife*, 1953—the next reference I can find in print.

**Edit**:

Safire wrote [another column](http://www.nytimes.com/1997/06/08/magazine/push-has-come-to-shove.html?pagewanted=all&src=pm) on the phrase in 1997 which drops the mention of rugby altogether. He concludes "a black-English origin for the phrase is pretty likely" and cites a 1954 example, four years earlier than *OED*'s earliest reference (1958). He also dug up this more plausible origin of the phrase:

> Other evidence there of the phrase's black origin is a recollection from Norman Pierce of Jack's Record Cellar in San Francisco of Shove Day, or Bump Day, the traditional Thursday off for domestic servants in the 1920's, ''on which blacks 'accidentally' jostled whites in public places, railways, streetcars, etc.''

**Edit #2**:

I just found another antedating of the phrase. [These](http://books.google.com/books?id=z3wGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22push%20come%20to%20shove%22&dq=%22push%20come%20to%20shove%22&hl=en&ei=LEX7TdvDO7Oz0AGUhdGlAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA) are from *Black Thunder* by [Arna Wendell Bontemps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arna_Wendell_Bontemps) (close friend of Langston Hughes), 1936:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=z3wGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22push+come+to+shove%22&dq=%22push+come+to+shove%22&hl=en&ei=LEX7TdvDO7Oz0AGUhdGlAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA]

Comment: You should send these antedatings to etymonline.com and the OED.

Comment: @Hugo: Just sent it to Etymonline. I'll do the same for OED, but can you tell me what they have for earliest occurrence? I don't have easy access.

Comment: I don't have OED access either, but your answer edit cites a 1958 citation.

Comment: So it does. I got that from Safire's 1997 article. Maybe someone here could confirm that that is still OED's earliest reference. I'd like to know before going through the OED submission process.

Comment: A few years later: the earliest OED reference for the exact phrase is from a 1898 newspaper in Georgia: “When ‘push comes to shove’ will editors of the Yellow Kid organs enlist?”. Earliest reference at all is from 1873 in _United Methodist Free Churches’ Mag._: “The proposed improvement is about to fail, when Push comes up behind it and gives it a shove, and Pull goes in front and lays into the traces; and, lo! the enterprise advances, the goal is reached!”.

Answer (score 4):

[Answers.com](http://www.answers.com/topic/if-push-comes-to-shove) also cites the rugby reference.  It also notes the other meaning of the phrase as in "They supposedly support equality, but when push comes to shove they always seem to promote a man instead of a woman".  I think the difference is "if" vs. "when".  I see think the "when" meaning is more prevalent.  It means "when actually tested".

Comment: Searching this corpus yielded 87 "when..." vs. 17 "if..." http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=8201178

Answer (score 3):

Push is just a push, and things have escalated to a shove now.  It now means business.  Escalate to get the thing accomplished.

Comment: Yes, a shove is a much more intense push, sometimes using up all your remaining energy; so that would seem the right metaphor for "as a last resort".

Answer (score 2):

Well my understanding of the phrase has always been this:

Pushing and shoving is a way of referring to fighting, particular little man-to-man arguments.  They start with a push and a shove, so when "push comes to shove", it means a fight will break out.  Fighting is the last resort, or at least the least desired outcome of an argument.

Answer (score 2):

The earliest instance of the idiom I found is from Central Valley project of California: [Hearings](https://books.google.it/books?id=_39IAAAAMAAJ&q=inauthor:%22United%20States.%20Congress.%20House.%20Committee%20on%20flood%20control%22&dq=inauthor:%22United%20States.%20Congress.%20House.%20Committee%20on%20flood%20control%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R2rMVIGEOIWqywPSqYLoCg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAg). United States. Congress. House. Committee on Flood Control
February 7-9, **1935**: [page 52](https://books.google.it/books?id=gg-u_Lh3bDcC&q=%22push%20comes%20to%20shove%22&dq=%22push%20comes%20to%20shove%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R2jMVJOMJKGBywPBwoKYCQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg)

[image]

It's my guess that the idiom is derived from the  fixed expression ***push and shove***, which Wikipedia calls [Siamese twins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_twins_(linguistics)) or binomials. The order of the words are never reversed and they are usually conjoined by the words *and* or *or*.

> The words constituting a Siamese twins phrase may be **synonyms**, antonyms, include alliterations or similar-sounding words that often rhyme.

The combination: *push and shove* is firmly rooted in the 19th century (earlier instances I did not find in Google Books) and  clearly expresses a frustrated type of struggle, where people or animals have to fight each other in order to reach their objective.  As seen in the following excerpts:

[Young Men's Christian Association](https://books.google.it/books?id=747OAAAAMAAJ&q=%22push%20and%20shove%22&dq=%22push%20and%20shove%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PXDMVNeAI4q_ygOQiYLoAQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwCTgK), **1903**
[image]

*[The Nursery](https://books.google.it/books?id=Bf4BAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA21&dq=%22push%20and%20shove%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=J3jMVMf8EILWygO66oHABA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22push%20and%20shove%22&f=false)* by Fanny P. Searverns  **1867**
The Donkey and The Pigs

[image]

*[The London Review and Weekly Journal of Politics, Literature, Art...](https://books.google.it/books?id=2n1NAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA200&dq=%22push%20and%20shove%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qXjMVOaZOsPnywP1r4K4AQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22push%20and%20shove%22&f=false)*  **1860**

> For the rest of us, we push and shove ourselves into the best places, after the manner of Englishmen, that is, to our mutual discomfort, and without the least necessity ; and then we look round, and compose ourselves, to the due enjoyment of the imposing spectacle.

[Missionary Chronicle](https://books.google.it/books?id=B35MAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA164&dq=%22push%20and%20shove%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Q3XMVOXiGsPRywPJ2IHAAQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22push%20and%20shove%22&f=false) *Presbyterian Church in the U.S.A. Board of Foreign Missions, ‎Presbyterian Church in the U.S.A*. **1844**

> Some go about begging and push and shove one another, [each greedy to get first]. Others go about begging unthreshed rice of the donor. They strive for food, transgressing the rules of propriety. They do not properly demean themselves.

From *push and shove* to "when push comes to shove" the path seems to me fairly straightforward. After all what is a *shove* if not a more decisive and aggressive type of push? A *shove* represents a surge of energy, the last resort, the final action when no alternative option is available.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the Discworld books, Terry Pratchett alludes to the origin of this word as being midwifery (I think it's Nanny Ogg who has the relevant line).

I imagine he just made this up though...

Comment: interesting - we should chech it out

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it might have its origins in the 16th and early 17th century English, during the English Civil War. The phrase that comes to mimd is a description of what happens when opposing pike blocks engaged in melee. It was described as push of pike and musket butt.

That phrase would have percolated through the population easily since the civilian population was intimately associated with the armies. It could easily morph into push comes to shove as that rolls off the tongue so easily and aptly describes the soldiesr in the pike blocks doing exactly that.

Comment: Interesting theory. Do you have any references to support it?